# Problems with creating hyperlinks in header and footer

Tags: html, hyperlink

I have simple site without frameworks but .html files located in different folders and when i connect header and footer by short filename , it not works on all pages.(I cant use urls)
`<a href="../pages/about_me.php">About me</a>` - not working always
`<a href="https://mysiteisverybad.com/pages/about_me.php">About me</a>` - cant use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you want to create a hyperlink in HTML the links must be in the same folder.
Hope that work.
Best wishes.